# Separating our JIRA Kanban Boards

Tags: jira, jql

I have a question on separating our JIRA Boards. Please see below.

Data Management Kanban Board

```
project = WFDM4 ORDER BY cf[10005] ASC
352 Issues
```

Data Landscape Kanban Board

```
project = WFDM4 AND labels in (dl_board) ORDER BY priority DESC, updated DESC
1 Issues
```

How can I edit the JQL for Data Management Kanban Board to separate the JIRA Kanban Boards?
Attempt:

```
project = WFDM4 AND labels not in  (dl_board) ORDER BY priority DESC, updated DESC
259 Issues
```

There seem to be some missing issues in the new JQL since it is only returning 259 Issues. I would like these Kanban Boards to be completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is because there are some issues without any labels.
When an issue has no label, all comparsions returns false, even when the comparsion is an negation.

Try this:

```
project = WFDM4 AND (
   (labels is empty)
   OR (labels not in (dl_board) )
ORDER BY ...
```